# Linux Mint Tessa - errors were encountered while processing

Tags: linux-mint

New linux user, tried to use sudo apt-get upgrade, was going good until this happened:

`dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
 gconf2
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Every time I try to upgrade, this happens. I've tried removing gconf2 and re-installing it, Ive tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and get the same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with Linux Mint 19 Tessa.

This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gconf2
```

Found in here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/77475/i-encountered-a-gconf2-error-while-installing-some-packages-what-should-i-do